# Using Pathlib to search for a matching file?

Tags: python

I have the following method:

```
def file_search(self, fundCodes, type):
    funds_string = '_'.join(sorted(fundCodes))
    files = set(os.listdir(self.unmappedDir))
    file_match = 'citco_unmapped_{type}_{funds}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(type=type, funds=funds_string, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
    if file_match in files:
        filename = os.path.join(self.unmappedDir, file_match)
        return self.read_file(filename)
    else:
        Logger.error('No {type} file/s found for {funds}, between {start} and {end}'.format(type=type, funds=fundCodes,
                                                                                            start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate))
```

The method is part of a Module that searches for files matching a certain format.  `fundCodes` would be an array and the rest of the info for the file comes from its initialized variables.

So the method would find a file like this one, if it matches the format:

`citco_unmapped_trades_PCASPE_PUPSFF_2018-07-19_2018-07-20.csv`

In my directory.

I was told to look into [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) since I might be overengeneering this, but I'm not sure how else I could improve the method other than re-writing it with `pathlib` somehow. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: btw using built-ins names for your objects (`type` in particular case) may cause a lot of problems

Comment: Ah good call, i'll change that. Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can copy-paste your class definition and see how we can help

Comment: `pathlib` is (generally) a good replacement for `os.path`. If you are simply rewriting the module to pathlib, you might as well use f-string rather than `.format` imo. If the module is *not* working, you should point out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-writing it as so:

```
def file_search(self, fundCodes, dataType):
    funds_string = '_'.join(sorted(fundCodes))
    file_match = 'citco_unmapped_{type}_{funds}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(type=dataType, funds=funds_string,
                                                                          start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
    unmapped_file = Path(self.unmappedDir, file_match)
    if unmapped_file.exists():
        return self.read_file(unmapped_file)
    else:
        Logger.error('No {type} file/s found for {funds}, between {start} and {end}'.format(type=dataType, funds=fundCodes,
                                                                                            start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate))
```